# Nginx docker - basic nginx.conf file to accept HTTPS

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I am spinning up a dev environment for an application using docker/docker-compose. I am attempting to set up the app to accept HTTPS protocol (for dev a self-signed cert using openssl is sufficient) but am having issues.

My `docker-compose` file (note I am mounting volumes for the certs as well as the nginx.conf file shared below):

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /homes/edmisml/nginx_docker_vol/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /etc/ssl:/ssl/
  myservice:
    build: ./erschatbot_frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
```

My very simple nginx.conf to allow HTTPS so far:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
         }

   server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/data-access.log combined;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       }
    }
}
```

When I spin up the containers using docker-compose I get the following error

```
webserver     | 2021/03/09 14:53:27 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
webserver     | nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
```

So I assume this is a syntax error but I do not see the particular issue. For reference I am roughly following the guide [here](https://stackify.com/how-to-configure-https-for-an-nginx-docker-container/).

I am a total nginx noob - can someone help me out?

UPDATE: fixed silly typo at line 25 (missing semi-colon) but am still receiving errors when visting the `https:<url>`. Error:

```
webserver     | 2021/03/09 15:31:44 [error] 32#32: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.75.226.54, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon on line 25. 
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you missed this?

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;

        ssl_certificate /ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/data-access.log combined;

        location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host; // <--- here
       }
    }
}
```